# Google search using python and scrape first result

Tags: python, excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I have a list (in Excel) of the names of several companies. When I run a Google search on the "company name" and "address", I get the address as the first result in a box.

I would like to get this result in the cell opposite to each company name. Could someone please help me with the script and the right packages to run the search and scrape the first result into excel?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking someone to write a program for you. That's not what this is for. Have you tried writing it yourself and are running into *specific* problems?

Try coding it and report back if you have problems. This website should get you started with selenium's webdriver.

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp